# How to force printf to return a negative value in c?

Tags: c, printf, return-value

I need to write a C program in which `printf` should return a negative value. It should be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int ret_val;
    ret_val = printf(something);
    printf("%d", ret_val);
}
```

The output of this should be a negative number(ret_val should be negative).

Comment: Create an output error, `printf` returns a negative value on failure.

Comment: Sounds fishy.  what are you doing?

Comment: While linux specific, you can redirect stdout to >/dev/full , which will produce an error when it's written to. Though the error might not show up until you call fflush(), or set stdout to non-buffered before callign printf.

Comment: @nos: How did I manage not to know about `/dev/full` until now?

Comment: @Wug: Nothing fishy :). I was explaining to my friend that printf can return negative.

Comment: Theoretically this might be used as an exploit somewhere... it might be used to cause a buffer overflow in a poorly written program.

Answer (score 5):

Invoke an encoding error:

```
int ret = 0;
ret = printf("%lc", (wint_t) -1);
printf("%d\n", ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect `stdout` to an invalid handle before doing your `printf`. For example, reopen it in read-only mode

```
freopen("fff", "r", stdout);
```

Comment: That causes the first printf to return a negative value, but it fails to meet the specification that the second printf prints a negative number, since that second printf cannot be performed without an error.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: Wrong. There has never been such "specification". The question is about making `printf` return a negative value. Period. The code sample in the OP is just a "something like" example, which can also be made to work by redirecting `stdout` again (to a file).

Comment: The asker displayed a program with two printf statements and specified the output should be a negative number.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: No, the author prepended the program with "it should be something like this" remark, meaning that it was just an example to illustrate the request, not a part of the "specification". Speaking in the formal language, the code serves *illustrative*, not *normative* purposes.